# Convert CvSeq to vector<cv::Point>?

Tags: ios, opencv

I am new to openCV. i am working for the image processing application. i need to convert the `CvSeq` to `vector<cv::Point>`.

```
void find_squares( IplImage* img , cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point>>&squares){
    IplImage* newimg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    IplImage* cannyimg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    IplImage* greyimg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    IplImage* testimg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    // convert the loaded image to a canny image
    cvCvtColor(img, greyimg, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvCanny(greyimg, cannyimg, 50, 150, 3);

    // necessary to convert loaded image to an image with channel depth of 1
    cvConvertImage(cannyimg, newimg);
    cvConvertImage(img, testimg);

    // allocate necessary memory to store the contours
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvMemStorage* canny_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    // find the contours in both the loaded image and the canny filtered image
    cvFindContours(testimg, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour),
                   CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_CODE);
    cvFindContours(newimg, canny_storage, &canny_contours, sizeof(CvContour),
                   CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_CODE);

    // draw the contours on both the loaded image and the canny filtered image
    cvDrawContours(testimg, contours, cvScalar(255,255,255), cvScalarAll(255), 100);

     cvDrawContours( newimg, canny_contours, cvScalar(255,255,255), cvScalarAll(255),100);

}
```

I want to convert the `contours` to `cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point>>`. i don't know want to do next.

Please give me any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is too long to be written here. It took whole chapter in a book to describe how CvSeq works and why ("Learning OpenCV" by Gary Bradski and Adrian Kaehler, chapter 8).

More importantly, you shouldn't learn this now. C interface is already deprecated and when OpenCV 3.0 (that currently under development) will be released this interface will be removed completely. That means using Mat instead of IplImage* and using functions without 'cv' prefix in their name. See [documentation of findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours). Your code will look like this:

```
vector<vector<cv::Point>> contours;
cv::findContours(testimg, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_CODE);
```

**Edit (answer to comment):**

Your drawing function will be:

```
drawContours(testimg, contours, -1, 255, CV_FILLED);
```

See [documentation of drawContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#drawcontours).

Comment: Show     cvDrawContours(testimg, contours, cvScalar(255,255,255), cvScalarAll(255), 100); insted of this i should use cv::findContours(testimg, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_CODE);

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your comment

Comment: i am saying that after findcounters how can i get four points on imageview